# CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE not sending cookie parameter

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, curl

I'm having a problem requesting a page with a cookie using PHP's cURL library. The code is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://website.com/members',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../cookie.txt'
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

`dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../cookie.txt'` points to a valid cookie file, as I've verified by dumping the contents of that file using PHP. So PHP does have read permissions for that file (and execute, I set that file to chmod 0777). When I dump the request I see this:

```
* About to connect() to website.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 88.19.264.3... * connected
> GET /members HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Cookie: __utmz=1.1383258121.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=1; __utmb=1.8.10.1383258121; __utma=1.259269816.1383258121.1383258121.1383258121.1; sync=1; lang=en; https=1
Host: website.com

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2013 22:36:07 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=8
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<
* Connection #0 to host website.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

The cookie header is being set with the contents of `cookie.txt`, however it's missing the `auth` parameter which is required to authenticate the session. The `auth` parameter definitely exists in the `cookie.txt` file, however.

I just don't get why cURL would only send some parameters in the `cookie.txt` file, and not the `auth` parameter. I've tried to remove all the unneeded parameters leaving only `auth` however it still doesn't get sent.

For reference, the `auth` parameter looks like this:

```
.website.com        TRUE    /       TRUE    1385850138.917861       auth    y2a4232344b4x2h403a423fgw2c443g4u2c49hg48494g4a4q2o5g4g4v274b4i4a4k5e4e4y2a4c4g4s2l56323b4d453s5946453b4t2c4y7d47336
```

I dumped the cookie file using cURL on the command line so I know it's the right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4. parameter TRUE means the cookie will only be sent through secure connections.

Cookie file format: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-03/0099.html

About secure cookies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie

Comment: The cURL request is requesting a https page, though. Wouldn't it through up an error if it can't achieve a secure connection?

Comment: Are you sure? It connects to port 80 which means plain http.

Comment: Ah, good point. Is there a chance cURL is silently connecting to http rather than https when it can't establish a https connection? I'll check to see if I have SSL support within PHP.

Comment: maybe this helps: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);